# Como eliminar a pausa entre animações dum AnimationSet?

Tags: android, animação

Eu tenho a seguinte rotina:

```
private void move(float graus1, float graus2, float xx1, float xx2, float yy1, float yy2) {
        animSet = new AnimationSet(false);      
        rotate = new RotateAnimation(graus1,graus2,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, .5f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 2f);         
        translate = new TranslateAnimation(xx1, xx2, yy1, yy2);         
        rotate.setDuration(2000);       
        translate.setDuration(2000);
        translate.setStartOffset(rotate.getDuration());
        animSet.addAnimation(rotate);
        animSet.addAnimation(translate);                
        animSet.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        animSet.setFillAfter(true);
        animSet.setStartOffset(0);      
        myimagem.startAnimation(animSet);   
    }
```

Funciona beleza. Porem quando acaba o rotate há uma parada para depois começar o translate. Como não haver esta pausa, e a imagem seguir na mesma velocidade todo o percurso?
Já tentei de tudo. Mudei o interpolador com varios tipos e nada...
Agradeço alguma ajuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta informar o **AnimationSet** que deve usar o mesmo **Interpolator** em todas as animações:

```
animSet = new AnimationSet(true);
```

O *delay*, que notou, se deve à criação de um novo **Interpolator** para gerir a animação seguinte do *set*.

O valor "booleano" passado ao construtor [AnimationSet(boolean shareInterpolator)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationSet.html#AnimationSet(boolean)) serve para isso mesmo.

Comment: ramaral, muito bem explicado. Deu certo... Muito Obg...

Comment: ramaral, me surgiu outras duas duvidas: Como é que eu obtenho o X e o Y da imagem em um determinado momento do percurso? no exemplo acima o tempo total da animacao é de 4000. Como eu sei qual é o valor do X e o Y, por exemplo, nos 2500? E a outra: Como é que ainda na execução da animação eu mudo o tempo (setDuration), ou seja, eu coloquei 2000 e 2000, mais ao clique de um botao eu quero diminuir ou aumentar a velocidade, por exemplo, para 1000 e 1000 ou 3000 e 3000, etc...?

Comment: Tudo isso é possível de ser feito(pelo menos o primeiro). Será mais fácil de fazer se, em vez de [View Animations](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/package-summary.html) que está obsoleto, usar [Property Animations](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html). No entanto, isso não é algo que exista já feito, terá porventura de usar um [ValueAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html) e implementar esses requisitos.

Comment: Uma boa fonte de informação sobre animações: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Animations

Comment: ramaral, já estou pesquisando e estudando o que voce comentou acima... Voce entende tambem de SQLite3? Pois eu postei um duvida... Abraços.